# Papers/Books dealing with closedness of the range of operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I have the following definition. A continuous linear operator $P:C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)\longrightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)$ is **globally solvable** if $P$ has closed range.

Of course I could replace $C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)$ for any topological vector space and the above definition would still make sense.

Are there papers or books dealing with such kind of concept (maybe in the context of Fréchet spaces)?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, there is the classical closed range theorem for Frechet spaces, see e.g. the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out =)